# Can you Sessionize Weblogs in an RDBMS

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, hadoop, rdbms

Just a general question.  Can you sessionize logs in an RDBMS?

For example, say you just have three columns 1) timestamp 2) URL 3) UserID is it possible to sessionize the logs based of X minutes of activity in a traditional RDBMS.  The output might look like four columns 1) timestamp 2) URL 3) UserID 4)SessionID.

I'd assume it's not, but want to hear others opinion.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit tricky, but can be done using nested Windowed Aggregate Functions like

```
SELECT timestamp, UserID, URL,
   SUM(newSession) -- cumulative sum over 0/1
   OVER (PARTITION BY UserId
         ORDER BY timestamp
         ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS SessionID
FROM
 (
   SELECT 
      ts_col, UserID, URL,
      -- calculate the timestamp difference between current and previous row
      CASE WHEN timestamp - LAG(timestamp) 
                            OVER (PARTITION BY UserId 
                                  ORDER BY timestamp) > INTERVAL 'X minutes' 
           THEN 1  -- new session starts
           ELSE 0  -- part of the old session
      END AS newSession
 ) AS dt
```

Some DBMSes (e.g. Vertica & Aster) support sessionization using builtin functions, in others you might implement a User Defined Function.